# Django Exclude ForeignKey field from ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models:

```
class Vehicle(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Driver(Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, related_name='owned_vehicle')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

now on my forms.py:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    drivers = Driver.objects.order_by('name')
    drivers_list = forms.ModelChoiceField(drivers, empty_label='* Driver *', label='Driver')
```

The problem is `drivers_list` also includes the `vehicles` in the list.
How can I prevent this form from including the ForeignKey field into the ModelChoiceField?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using model form for drivers,

```
class DriverForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['name', 'vehicle']
```

For your own forms,

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    driver_list = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Driver.objects.order_by('name'))
    # then other attributes which you want to map with driver
```